# jQuery: how to allign image in the middle of a div using each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a script in order to center in the middle all images in a div using the each function. This is the code:

```
        $('.column').each(function (){

           var colHeight = $(this).innerHeight();
           var colWidth = $(this).width(); 



           var getCenter = (colHeight - imgHeight);            
           var toBeCentered = (getCenter / 2);

           var toReduceWidth = (colWidth - imgWidth);
           var getReducedWidth = (toReduceWidth / 2);      



         $('.myImg').css({'top': toBeCentered + 'px','left': 0});


        });
```

With the var called **toBeCentered** I get the height of all divs

```
$('.myImg').css({'top': toBeCentered + 'px','left': 0});
```

The piece of code above displays always the last one .col div height and not all beginning from the very first.
How can I set the related div height to the images?

Comment: why dont you do this with css?

Comment: I also tried with css using dispaly:table-cell etc...but it does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like:

```
$('.column').each(function (){
    // ...
    $(this).find('.myImg').css({'top': toBeCentered + 'px','left': 0});

});
```

Because you are setting css attributes for all `.myImg` objects in every iteration of `each` function. Above solution will work if `.myImg` objects are in `.column` class.

Answer (score 0):

And this is the non-script css solition;

```
.column{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
.myImg{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```